# Fibers of extension of scalars to algebraic closure of an affine variety is of dimension 0.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, field-theory, tensor-products, krull-dimension

> Let $X$ be an affine variety over $k$ and $\overline{k}$ be the algebraic closure of $k$. Then the projection morphism $X_\overline{k} = X \times _k \overline{k} \to X$ has dimension 0 fibers.

Say $X = \text{Spec } A$. Then $X_\overline{k} = \text{Spec} (A \otimes _k \overline{k})$

The fiber of the homomorphism at point $p \in X$ is

$$X_p = X_\overline{k} \times _X \text{Spec} k(p) = \text{Spec} (A \otimes_k \overline{k} \otimes_A k(p)) = \text{Spec}(A_p/m_p A_p \otimes _k \overline{k}) $$

Thus, it is equivalent to say that the ring $A_p / m_p A_p \otimes_k \overline{k}$ has (Krull) dimension $0$. As far as I know, the tensor of two fields is not necessarily a field, thus ruling out any trivial dimension considerations. I am not really sure how to think of prime ideals in such a tensor product. Any ideas to tackle this would be appreciated.

An idea I'm formulating right now is that $k(p) = A_p / m_p A_p$ is a field extension of $k$. Thus the tensor is simply an extension of scalars, from one field to its algebraic closure. Is this perhaps equivalent to considering the same field $k(p)$ but now explicitly embedded in this larger field, namely the closure?

Comment: Just to put this in the natural generality: an integral morphism always has dimension $0$ fibers.

Comment: @Hoot:   ... except for the empty fibers of dimension $-\infty$  .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $k\to \bar k$ is integral so is $k(p)\to k(p)\otimes_k\bar k$ ([Atiyah-Macdonald](https://books.google.it/books?id=HOASFid4x18C&hl=fr):  Chap.5, Ex.3).
But then $\dim  k(p)=\dim k(p)\otimes_k \bar k$ ([Matsumura](https://books.google.fr/books/about/Commutative_Ring_Theory.html?id=yJwNrABugDEC&redir_esc=y): Exer. 9.2), so that indeed $\dim k(p)\otimes_k \bar k=0$.

**Edit: the fibers are actually finite**
Since the ring  $k(p)\otimes_k \bar k$ is noetherian of dimension zero, it is artinian and has thus finite discrete spectrum.
So all the fibers of $X_\overline{k} \to X$ are actually finite discrete schemes.
This was not obvious, because the scheme morphism itself  $X_\overline{k} \to X$ is far from finite in general: think of $X=\operatorname {Spec}(k)=$  a point!

Comment: Thanks for the concise solution. For future readers, a reference for the Matsumura exercise is contained here: http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~zerz/ast10/dim1.pdf

Comment: Dear Georges, why give an exercise as a reference for one of the most famous theorems in commutative algebra: the Krull-Cohen-Seidenberg Theorem?

Comment: Dear @user26857, because  I'm not sure  what the OP knows. For example, I don't know the terminology Krull-Cohen-Seidenberg since I learned commutative algebra from Atiyah-Macdonald :-) (and I haven't even read it through yet !)

Answer (score 5):

It suffices to show that if $K$ and $L$ are two fields extending a field $k$ and $L$ is algebraic over $k$, then $\dim K\otimes_k L=0$ (let $K=A_p/m_pA_p$ and $L=\overline{k}$).  Let $R=K\otimes_k L$; to show that $R$ has dimension $0$, it suffices to show that for any homomorphism $R\to F$ where $F$ is a field, the image of $R$ in $F$ is a field (if $p\subset q$ are primes in $R$, then you could take $F$ to be the field of fractions of $R_p/q$ and $R\to F$ to be the canonical map).

So let $\varphi:R\to F$ be a homomorphism to a field.  Then $\varphi$ restricts to a homomorphism $K\to F$, and the image $\varphi(K)$ is a subfield of $F$.  Since $L$ is algebraic over $k$, $R$ is generated as an $K$-algebra by elements that are algebraic over $K$, and hence every element of $R$ is algebraic over $K$.  It follows that every element of $\varphi(R)$ is algebraic over $\varphi(K)$.  It follows that for any $\alpha\in\varphi(R)$, $\varphi(K)[\alpha]$ is actually a field, and so $\varphi(R)$ is a field.

Comment: This observation and the subsequent proof is very clever. May I ask how you thought of it?

Comment: Well, the idea is that you should really think of prime ideals as homomorphisms from your ring to a field (up to a certain equivalence relation).  When you mod out a maximal ideal, you get a field, so maximal ideals correspond to such homomorphisms for which the image is a field.  So to say that every prime is maximal (i.e., the ring is $0$-dimensional) is to say that the image of every homomorphism to a field is a field.